# Naming Angular directives (ng- vs data-ng-)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What is the recommended practice for labelling Angular directives?

Other than html validation, are there any other benefits to prefixing both the in-built and my own custom directives with "`data-`"?

Or is it unnecessary clutter?

Comment: In browsers that look at that strictly, your app might not work without it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ng-app and data-ng-app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app)

Comment: Should the post asked after this one not have been flagged as a duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-app V/S data-ng-app in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110450/ng-app-v-s-data-ng-app-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say data- would be best practice. Since this will allow the html to validate, it should be a standard practice for developers. It may cause a bit of clutter, but overall I think it helps maintain the intergrity of the app and of the developer. And seeing as it doesn't matter to angular that I can tell thus far, then there really is no reason not to use data-.

Comment: hey! 5 bytes is not nothing

Comment: @djeendo you're absolutely right, but i would argue that it's worth the hits. especially if you are going to minify the html anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-ng-, instead of ng-, if you want to make your page HTML valid.

This wont give error

```
<div ng-app="">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<p ng-bind="name"></p>

</div>
```

This will give error

```
<div data-ng-app="scope" data-ng-init="name='test'"

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="name"></p>
<p data-ng-bind="name"></p>

</div>
```