# What is the difference between ng-app and data-ng-app?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have begun to learn about AngularJS and am confused about what the differences are between the `ng-app` and `data-ng-app` directives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-app vs. data-ng-app, what is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589853/ng-app-vs-data-ng-app-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: @chenrui - this Q came first btw. (April 24 vs May 16)

Comment: Your application is not gonna get impacted and Angular will work as expected even if you use ng-app or data-ng-app but as mentioned by @user2289659 making use of data-* is introduced custom attribute standard from HTML5 onwards

Answer (score 124):

Most of these answers are simply saying *makes template valid HTML*, or *HTML Validator Compliant*, without explaining what THOSE terms mean, either.

I do not know for sure, but I'm guessing that these terms apply to HTML validation programs that scan your code for standards compliance - kind of like lint.  They do not recognize `ng-app` as a valid attribute.  They expect non default HTML attributes to be prefaced with

`data-attribute_name_here`.

So, the creators of `AngularJS` have created alternate names for their directives that include the `data-` in front of them so that HTML validator programs will "like" them.

Comment: +1 for the "Ok. So, what does 'validator compliant' mean, anyway?" approach. If you had done the research you would find out that you are guessing mostly right. =)

Comment: Valid HTML isn't for HTML validators. Browsers parse HTML. If you start deviating from the HTML specification, there's no guarantee that your HTML will be parsed correctly.

Comment: Yes, the validators are a means to the end. The goal is to make your web pages as close as possible to the specs, which maximises the number of browsers - old, present, and future - in which your app will actually work as expected. In the case of "data-*", there's also the risk browsers could introduce the same attribute as a standard, which would collide with your app's attribute. Also, sticking to standards like this will help tools (e.g. editors) make sense of it and make them more useful to you.

Comment: @Blender "there's no guarantee that your HTML will be parsed correctly", the same can be said for valid HTML.

Comment: @twiz Yes, but wouldn't you rather reduce the chance of problems by adhering to the agreed standard, like just about everyone else?

Comment: @Chuck I was just pointing out that browsers don't necessarily follow the spec. Your point is valid, but in this case I think it is insignificant if you leave off the `data-`. I doubt that the HTML specs are going to start including attributes that are prefixed with `ng-`.

Comment: @twiz Why take the chance? The only valid reason I can think of leaving it off is laziness...? It also means it's harder to debug your HTML because any validators will be throwing up lots of errors. I don't see the point myself.

Comment: @Chuck I'm not suggesting you do it one way or the other, just that the issue is not particularly important. We may as well debate spaces vs tabs while we're at it. haha

Comment: @twiz I'd certainly turn my nose up at someone's code if they didn't include the 'data-' -- they just made my life harder for no good reason.

Comment: @Chuck Are you suggesting spaces are better than tabs?!? Madness!!

Comment: While it used to be true that non-standard attributes are left up to the browser's interpretation, HTML 5 specifies the behavior of non-standard attributes (and other sloppy, sloppy markup).

Comment: down-voted because Angular does not have multiple names - it has only ngApp and the HTML attribute name is converted by the Angular scanning algorithm by stripping off the 'data-' or the 'x-'. It also strips out the '-' from between 'ng' and 'app', and lastly converts lower case to upper camel-case style.

Answer (score 41):

None in terms of the runtime behavior, those are just different styles of naming directives as described here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> Directives have camel cased names such as ngBind. The directive can be
>   invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these
>   special characters :, -, or _. Optionally the directive can be
>   prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant. Here
>   is a list of some of the possible directive names: ng:bind, ng-bind,
>   ng_bind, x-ng-bind and data-ng-bind.

As you can see from reading this the `data-` can be used to make your HTML pass HTML validator tests/

Comment: Where in the specification of HTML allows for this?

Comment: @user1876508: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Answer (score 6):

You can declare the angular namespace `<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app>`

Comment: This appears to be only applicable for legacy apps: "If you choose to use the old style directive syntax ng: then include xml-namespace in html to make IE happy. (This is here for historical reasons, and we no longer recommend use of ng:.)". Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Answer (score 5):

In modern browsers there is no difference, but in older IEs, they won't work unless you declare an XML namespace defining it.

There is also a validation difference in that `ng-app` is not valid XHTML, and will cause your webpage to fail HTML validations. Angular allows you to prefix its directives with `data-` or `x-` to allow it to validate.

Comment: This appears to be only true if you're using "ng:". I believe "data-ng-" should validate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use data-ng-, instead of ng-, if you want to make your page HTML valid.

This **will** throw an error

```
<div ng-app="">

  <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
  <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <p ng-bind="name"></p>

</div>
```

This **won't** throw an error

```
<div data-ng-app="scope" data-ng-init="name='test'">

  <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
  <p>Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="name"></p>
  <p data-ng-bind="name"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain why would the first scenario throw an error?

Comment: This is referencing w3c validation.

Answer (score 3):

The basic difference between these two terms is that data-ng-app validates the HTML while the latter don't.Functionality remains the same.
For more reference you can try w3Validator.

Answer (score -2):

Absolutely there is no difference between the two, except that certain HTML5 validators will throw an error on a property like ng-app, but they don't throw an error for anything prefixed with data-, like data-ng-app. So using data- prefix with our angular directives is good.

Even you can make use angular directives in below mentioned ways
ng-bind, ng:bind, ng_bind, data-ng-bind, x-ng-bind