# include page with ng-include, angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Im trying to include a file with ng-include, but it don't work. The file should be included when you press on a button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getPartial()">Jämför</button>
```

Here is my function in the controller:

```
$scope.getPartial = function() {
            $scope.showCompare = '../partials/compare.html';
            console.log($scope.showCompare);
        };
```

And here is my div:

```
<div data-ng-include data-ng-src="showCompare"></div>
```

Nothing is included. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: <div data-ng-include="showCompare"></div> try it

Comment: @ThomasP1988: What is the difference between ng-include and data-ng-include?

Comment: look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
<div data-ng-include data-ng-src="showCompare"></div>
```

to either this:

```
<div data-ng-include src="showCompare"></div>
```

or this:

```
<div data-ng-include="showCompare"></div>
```