# ui-view not allowed on element at this point

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to use ui-router, i'm using Netbeans when i add ui-view to a div element NB is telling me ui-view is not allowed as an attr at this point? why not whats wrong with it? here is my code that's not working.

```
<div id="kindle" ng-controller="kindle">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div ui-view="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Its most likely just not an attribute netbeans recognizes. All angular directives can be prefixed with `data-` so they appear just like an ordinary data attribute.

Use `data-ui-view` to solve your problem:

```
<div id="kindle" data-ng-controller="kindle">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div data-ui-view="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Many angular developers prefix their directives in this way so that their app will pass html validators that dont recognize the attributes.

See this question for more information:
[What is the difference between ng-app and data-ng-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app)

Answer (score 1):

Add Angularjs plugins into NB

//Here's link For NB 7     http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40296/angularjs-tools

or   prefix all directive with data- as suggested by agconti