# Angular Js difference between ng-init and data-ng-init

Tags: angularjs

I am leaning Angular Js. I found many authors use ng-init and many authors use data-ng-init. I tried to search difference but could not get appropriate answer. If someone knows difference between them, then please share your answer.

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ng-app and data-ng-app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app)

Comment: All angular attribute directives can be writen as `ng-thing` or `data-ng-thing`. Both are 100% equivalent.

Answer (score 12):

Interesting question. From [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp):

> You can use data-ng-, instead of ng-, if you want to make your page
> HTML valid.

HTML Validators will throw an error with property like `ng-init`, but if we give a prefix with `data-`(e.g: `data-ng-init`), HTML Validators accept it and it will be valid.

You can read more details at here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Note: `data-*` attributes are the way to extend HTML.

Answer (score 6):

data-ng-init is HTML5 validate code where ng-init does not valid code in terms of HTML5. This is applicable for all angular directive.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally there is no difference between the two in terms of functionality but with only validation.

After the inception of HTML5, the code editor like Visual Studio, highlights the 'ng-', as something which is invalid. But actually it's valid, so there is a way to make the code editor understand that the attribute of AngularJS is a valid one by prefixing it with 'data-ng-*'.

So when used the prefix, in any HTML5 code editor, it doesn't underlines the attributes and treats them as valid.

This was  the original purpose of the 'data-*' prefix.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 validators will throw an error on ng-app. when we use data- as prefix it simply ignore the throw an error