# In angular js {{i.link}} for attribute href on element a showing w3c validation error

Tags: html, angularjs, w3c-validation

My Html code with Angular js:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="i in items | searchFor:searchString | limitTo:limit" >
                        <p><a href="{{i.link}}" class="search-link">{{i.title}}</a></p>
                        <p>{{i.description}}</p>
                        <p><a class="small" href="{{i.link}}">{{i.link}}</a></p>                
                    </li>
```

W3c Validation giving error like below :
Bad value {{i.link}} for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in path segment: { is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ng-href for this. Angular will transform it to the correct value.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Finally - using data-ng-href will solve the problem with validation problems. (Related SO question [What is the difference between ng-app and data-ng-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app))

Comment: ng-href is also giving error, but i have used data-ng-href then it's working fine.thanks for suggestion

Comment: Yeah, you are right - this SO question is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref). That is what AngularJS recommends. The W3C validation error will also get resolved. Also if you use `href` there will be issue of broken link.