# How to keep single div and same height for both the columns

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need one DIV - like `wss name     [WAIT LOADER ONLY IF ON LOADING TIME]`

I tried below way where first column height is different then second column. How can i achive this with single row.  first column has static text but, second column only some time come. But i need - `alert alert-info` applied with same height of div remains.

```
 <div class="row" ng-controller="indexController" ng-hide="!globals.currentUser">
        <div class="alert alert-info col-md-6">
            Current Workspace:<strong>{{currentWorkspace}}</strong>
        </div>
        <div data-ng-if="loading" class="col-md-6">
            Processing...<img src="../../Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please let me know if any way to achieve this or any bootstrap style.

Comment: why are you using the directive data-ng-if instead of ng-if?

Comment: @RafaRomero It is the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app

Comment: its just for html5 compatibility. its not an issue here actually.

Comment: can any one please share me solution for bootstrap css here.

Comment: Ups, sorry, I was not aware about that!

Comment: fine... please share if above issue known.

Comment: It may solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height.

Answer (score 0):

Use display:flex property for the parent of the column.