# angular different types of prefixes

Tags: angularjs

I have begun to learn angular js for some time and so far I have used 2 types of prefixes. They are the `ng-` and `data-ng`. But when I go through angular library I found this array.

`var ngAttrPrefixes = ['ng-', 'data-ng-', 'ng:', 'x-ng-'];`

So is this mean there are 4 types of prefixes available in angular. So what are the differences of each other. What are the situations that need to decide which prefix need to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`angular-documentation`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive),

> AngularJS normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

based on above statement below all are valid directives

1. ng-bind
2. ng:bind
3. ng_bind
4. data-ng-bind
5. x-ng-bind

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/fg8cUFi3Ja25O7csW8qy?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks @Sajeetharan. i can understand since html case insensitive they are using lower case and dash line. but why so many prefixes. only one type is enough ne

Comment: None in terms of the runtime behavior, those are just different styles of naming directiveshttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app

Comment: well turns out html validation programs don't recognize `ng-app` attr. thats why they used different prefixes to support validation programs