# Custom owl carousel directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I tried to convert the normal jQuery own carousel into Angular Directive. It doesn't work for me, show some angular errors which I couldn't find what is the issue.

**Controller**

```
$scope.defaultsCarousel = {
  'items': 4,
  'itemWidth': 300,
  'itemsDesktop': [1260, 3],
  'itemsTablet': [930, 2],
  'itemsMobile': [620, 1],
  'navigation': true,
  'navigationText': false
};
```

**HTML (Jade)**

```
custom-carousel(data-options="{{ defaultsCarousel }}", productid="#pl-1")
```

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('customCarousel', function(){
 function nextSlide(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.data.owlObject.next();
 };

 function prevSlide(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.data.owlObject.prev();
 };

 return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    link: function($scope, el, attrs){
        var options = $scope.$eval($(el).attr('data-options'));
        var product_id = attrs.productid;
        console.log(product_id);
        $(product_id).owlCarousel(options);
        var owl = $(product_id).data('owlCarousel');
        $(product_id).parent().find('.slide-control.right').on('click', {owlObject: owl}, nextSlide);
        $(product_id).parent().find('.slide-control.left').on('click', {owlObject: owl}, prevSlide);
     }
}
```

**ERROR**

> Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{] starting at [{4}].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is at this line `$scope.$eval($(el).attr('data-options'));`. This produce a parse syntax error. You have two options to fix it:

**OPTION 1:** get the options from `attrs` parameter of link directive function. ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/UyneSkUvH7YeePsbHE13?p=preview))

```
app.directive('customCarousel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

      var options = angular.fromJson(attrs.options);
      var product_id = attrs.productid;

      //..Rest of your logic
    }
  }
});
```

**OPTION 2:** get the options using scope one way binding. ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ev0fMAwPd7RvsUhhNEHt?p=preview))

```
app.directive('customCarousel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        options: '@',
        productid: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

      var options = angular.fromJson(scope.options);
      var product_id = scope.productid;

      //..Rest of your logic
    }
  }
});
```

---

*As you can see I'm getting the html `data-options` attribute as just `options`. That's because angularjs directives will ignore `data-*` prefix in all HTML elements and attributes names.*

More info:

- [Check this post about difference between ng-app and data-ng-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app/19827360#19827360)
- [Check basic data-* prefix docs in W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)