# What is the difference between `ng-if` and `data-ng-if`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the difference between `ng-if` and `data-ng-if` ?

They both seem to work in the same way, however i am not able to figure out the difference in them as not much material is available on `data-ng-if`.

Comment: simply No difference

Comment: I thought the two are literally the same thing. The `data-` prefix is just to make it compliant with HTML validators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ng-app and data-ng-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app)

Answer (score 3):

Technically both are same, but while validating your page [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) without defining `data-` on your custom attribute it will get failed, because `W3C validator` doesn't know anything about your custom attribute, so you must have to explicitly define `data-` before your custom attribute and then `W3C validator` will pass your HTML

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. The `$compile` service links them to the same directive.

From the Docs:

> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> 1. Strip `x-` and `data-` from the front of the element/attributes.
> 2. Convert the `:`, `-`, or `_`-delimited name to camelCase.
>
> For example, the following forms are all equivalent and match the `ngBind` directive:
>
> ```
> <div ng-controller="Controller">
>   Hello <input ng-model='name'> <hr/>
>   <span ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
>   <span ng:bind="name"></span> <br/>
>   <span ng_bind="name"></span> <br/>
>   <span data-ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
>   <span x-ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
> </div>
> ```

For more informaton, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)

Answer (score 0):

[arbitary attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)
HTML 5 has introduced data attribute. With the prefix of data- we can create custom data attributes such as
`<div id="thediv" data-ng-if="conditino"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

- Both are actually one and the same.
- Both are directives to specify Conditions.
- You can use ng-if or prefixing **ng-if** with data- or x- like **data-ng-if** or **x-ng-if**.
- Angular allows prefixing to its directives with data- or x- just for Validation due to "**HTML5 validator**".
- **Validation means you won't get any Warnings in Problems tab of Eclipse or any IDE that you are using like "Undefined attribute name (ng-model) at Eclipse".**
- You can use data-ng- instead of ng- if you want to make your page HTML valid nothing more than that.
- **The only difference** between these two terms is that **data-ng-app or x-ng-app validates the HTML while the ng-app didn't**.
- Functionality remains the same.