# ng-app V/S data-ng-app in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrapping

In AngularJS when using `ng-app`: `ng-app` found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application.

In some of the application it is being used as `data-ng-app`.

Is there any difference in both of the following declaration, If Yes what & If No then which one is significant and why ?

**1.**

```
 <body ng-app>
     <p>{{ 1 + 2 }}</p>
 </body>
```

**2.**

```
 <body data-ng-app>
     <p>{{ 1 + 2 }}</p>
 </body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-app vs. data-ng-app, what is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589853/ng-app-vs-data-ng-app-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ng-app and data-ng-app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184428/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-app-and-data-ng-app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both  and  are the same except for the fact that if you want your template/code to be according to be  HTML compliant and follow the best practices. Use data-ng-app.

This is what the official [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) quotes:

"Best Practice: Prefer using the dash-delimited format (e.g. ng-bind for ngBind). If you want to use an HTML validating tool, you can instead use the data-prefixed version (e.g. data-ng-bind for ngBind). The other forms shown above are accepted for legacy reasons but we advise you to avoid them."

Hope that answers your question.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

See the answer:

[ng-app vs. data-ng-app, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589853/ng-app-vs-data-ng-app-what-is-the-difference)

Only diffrence regarding html5 validation

Answer (score 1):

ng-app isn't strictly valid html.
Custom attributes should be prefixed with data- to be valid.

So angular added this syntax so users could still have valid html.
(Knockout also uses data- attributes.)
There is absolutely no difference in functionality.

Source:  [w3.org - custom data attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

ng-app and data-ng-app both are similar to each other, the only difference between them is sometimes HTML validators will show an error while using ng-app. so that time you can use data-ng-app.

note: x-ng-app also have the same property.  You can use x-ng-app too instead of using data-ng-app.